# Representing Hasse diagram of the Green order

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I need to represent graphs like the one below using xypics. They arise as the Hasse diagram of the Green order of finite semigroups (specifically finite Left Regular Bands) with the homomorphism to its support lattice. I know the very basics on how to draw lines and place points, but I don't know how one would draw ovaloids around a mass of points like in the image below. Also, I'd rather them not being ellipses.

Thank you for your time!

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Would you be okay with `tikz` instead?

Comment: @TomBombadil I would be okay with any solution. I don't know how dissimilar tikz and xy-pic are, but I'll adopt the one most suited for my purpose.

Comment: @AlainMatthes I have very limited experience with xy-pic, and none with tikz, so no special allegiance to either.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat There is `tikz-cd`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible to use `ellipse` but it's better to use a `rectangle` with `rounded corners` and `fit`.

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{fit}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[y=1.5cm,
       every fit/.style={inner sep=4mm,orange,dashed,rounded corners=4mm,draw,line width=0.6mm}]

 \path (3,8)   coordinate  (s0)
       (1,6)   coordinate  (s1)  (5,6) coordinate (s2)
       (1,4)   coordinate  (s3)  (3,4) coordinate (s4)   (5,4) coordinate (s5)
       (0,2)   coordinate  (s6)  (1,2) coordinate (s7)   (2,2) coordinate (s8) (3,1.5) coordinate (s9) 
       (4,2.5) coordinate (s10)  (6,2) coordinate (s11);

  \node[fit=(s0)] (f1){}; \node[fit=(s1)(s2)](f2){}; \node[fit=(s3)(s5)](f3){};     
  \node[fit=(s6)(s9)(s10)(s11)](f4){};
  \node[right] at (f1.east) {$A$};   \node[right] at (f2.east) {$B$}; \node[right] at (f3.east) {$C$};
  \node[right] at (f4.east) {$D$};
  \draw[thick] (s0) -- (s1) -- (s3) -- (s6)
               (s1) -- (s4) -- (s7) (s4) -- (s8) (s4) -- (s9)
               (s0) -- (s2) -- (s5) -- (s11)  
               (s5) -- (s10);
  \draw[thick,double=black,draw=white]  (s2) -- (s3) (s2) to[out=-100 ,in=10] (s6);
  \foreach \i in {0,...,11} \draw[fill=blue!40]  (s\i) circle (2pt);
  \draw[->] (6,5) -- node [above]{$\theta$} (8,5);
  \path (9,8) coordinate   (t0)
        (9,6) coordinate   (t1)  
        (9,4) coordinate   (t2) 
        (9,2) coordinate   (t3) ;
   \draw[thick] (t0) -- (t1) -- (t2) -- (t3);
   \foreach \i in {0,...,3} \draw[fill=red!40]  (t\i) circle (2pt);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely beautiful!

Comment: This is truly a great answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks but it's possible to use other methods with tikz to add the nodes without the coordinates. This solution uses basic tools of tikz.

Answer (score 7):

Using [xy-pic](http://www.tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/) as tagged by you.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[border=8]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
&&&  *=0{\xy(-3,-4);(5,4) **\frm<44pt>{.}\endxy \bullet}  \ar@{-}[dl] \ar@{-}[dr]  & \ar@{}[l]_{A}  &&&&*=0{\bullet} \ar@{-}[d] \\
&& *=0{\xy(-2,-2);(24,2) **\frm<44pt>{.}\endxy \bullet} \ar@{-}[dr] |!{[d];[rr]}\hole \ar@{-}[d] 
&& *=0{\bullet} \ar@/^1.7pc/@{}[dddlll] \ar@{-}[dll] & \ar@{}[l]_{B} &&&*=0{\bullet} \ar@{-}[d] \\
&& *=0{\xy(-2,-2);(24,2) **\frm<44pt>{.}\endxy \bullet} \ar@{-}[ddl] & *=0{\bullet} \ar@{-}[ddl] |!{[dd];[lll]}\hole \ar@{-}[dd] |\hole  \ar@{-}[ddr] |!{[dd];[uur]}\hole & *=0{\bullet} \ar@{-}[ddr] \ar@{-}[ddrr] & \ar@{}[l]_{C} & \ar@(r,l)[r]_{\theta} &&*=0{\bullet}\ar@{-}[dd]\\
& *=0{}\\
& *=0{\xy(-2,-2);(56,2) **\frm<44pt>{.}\endxy  \bullet} & *=0{\bullet} & *=0{\bullet} & *=0{\bullet} & *=0{\bullet} & *=0{\bullet} & \ar@{}[l]_>>>>>{D} &*=0{\bullet}\\
} 
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

> [image: certain graphs]

Comment: @OlivierBégassat if possible can you tell me what category do these "certain graphs" belong to ? My idea was to make the title of Q little more informative and easy for googlers and track back via tex.sx search. You can update the title to make for eg: "Representing automata or commutative diagrams ". Forgive my ignorance on this graphs topic

Comment: @HenriMenke more worried with no of upvotes to Q

Comment: @texenthusiast My goal is to use this to represent the Hasse diagram of the Green order on a finite Left Regular Band (LRB) together with the map to its ideal lattice.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Kindly update title as "Representing Hasse diagram of the Green order" and rest "on a finite Left Regular Band (LRB)" inside the Q content so that someone searching for this topic will find it.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat thanks to you for Q + considering my request to change title. Good luck :)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

`Asymptote` uses very natural approach to build this kind of graphs, see code below.
This graph is constructed with more-or-less manual positioning tweaks,
but it can be more automated if necessary.
`gr.tex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
unitsize(12mm);
pair d=(1,1.3); // next level offset
pair dout=(0.2,0.2);  // offset for the outline

pair[] A={(0,0)};

pair[] B={
(-d.x,-d.y),(d.x,-d.y)
};

pair[] C={
(-d.x,-2d.y),(0,-2d.y),(d.x,-2d.y)
};

pair[] D={
(-1.5d.x,-3d.y),
(   -d.x,-3d.y),
(-0.4d.x,-3d.y),
(      0,-3d.y-0.2d.y),
( 0.2d.x,-3d.y+0.2d.y),
( 1.2d.x,-3d.y),
};

real qx=2.5d.x;
pair[] q={
  (qx,A[0].y),
  (qx,B[0].y),
  (qx,C[0].y),
  (qx,D[0].y),  
};

pen dashed=linetype(new real[] {4,3}); // set up dashed pattern

real pw=0.8pt;
real gapw=3pw;

pen lpen=darkblue+pw;
pen dpen=orange+dashed+pw;

void Dot(pair v, pen p=currentpen){
  dot(v,p,UnFill);
}

void Dots(pair[] P){
  for(int i=0;i<P.length;++i){
    Dot(P[i]);
  }
}

void outline(pair[] v,pair dout=(0.2,0.2), string s="",pen p=dpen){
  pair l=v[0], r=v[v.length-1];
  pair c=0.5(l+r);

  guide g=
    (r+(dout.x,0))
    ..(r+(0,dout.y))
    --(l+(0,dout.y))
    ..(l+(-dout.x,0))
    ..(l+(0,-dout.y))
    --(r+(0,-dout.y))
    ..cycle
    ;
  draw(g,p); 
  label(s,r+dout,NE);
}

outline(A,"$A$");
outline(B,"$B$");
outline(C,"$C$");
outline(D,dout=(0.2,0.5),"$D$");

draw(B[0]--A[0]--B[1],lpen);
draw(C[0]--B[0]--C[1],lpen);

draw(C[0]--B[1],white+gapw);
draw(C[0]--B[1]--C[2],lpen);

draw(C[0]--D[0],lpen);

draw(C[1]--D[1],lpen);
draw(C[1]--D[2],lpen);
draw(C[1]--D[3],lpen);

draw(C[2]--D[4],lpen);
draw(C[2]--D[5],lpen);

guide g=B[1]..0.5(C[1]+C[2])..D[0];

draw(subpath(g,1,2),white+gapw);
draw(g,lpen);

draw(q[0]--q[1]--q[2]--q[3],lpen);

for(int i=0;i<q.length;++i){
  fill(circle(q[i],0.1),white);
}

Dots(A);Dots(B);Dots(C);Dots(D);Dots(q);

pair rarrowCenter=0.5(B[0]+C[0])+(3d.x,0);

label("$\theta \atop \longrightarrow$",rarrowCenter);

\end{asy}
%
\hsize8cm
\caption{Graph}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

To process it with `latexmk`, create file `latexmkrc`:

```
sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

and run `latexmk -pdf gr.tex`.

Or you can save the content between `\begin{asy}` `\end{asy}`
in, say, `g.asy` file, run `asy -f pdf g.asy` and get 
a standalone `g.pdf`, which can be included as a graphic file.

Comment: How could I make the gap larger between the two graphs, for instance adding 2 cm? Also, how would you make the letters A,B,C,D smaller?

Comment: @Olivier Bégassat: You can use for example `"$\scriptstyle A$"` instead of `"$A$"` to make the letters smaller. In this example `pair d=(1,1.3); // next level offset` is used to control the distance between nodes (its `x`-part `d.x=`1`) and levels (its `y`-part `d.y=1.3`). To increase the distance between sub-graphs, just increase `y`-part of `d`, for example `d=(1,1.3+1);` or `d=d+(0,1);`. Play  with `unitsize();` to get the results you want.

Comment: @cmhughes:You are right, for this particular MWE just `\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

With *TikZ*, this can be done quite easily using the `fit` library. First, define `node`s for all points that you want to fit (if you know your points in advance, then those forming the convex hull would be enough). Then you can make a new node using `[fit=(node 1)(node 2)...(node n)]`. To check that it works I did this 100 times for ten random points, as you can see the size of the output varies accordingly

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\foreach \y in {1,...,100}
{   \pgfmathsetseed{\y*101}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
        {   \node[fill=black,circle] (x\x) at (rnd*4-2,rnd*4-2) {};
        }
        \node[fit=(x1)(x2)(x3)(x4)(x5)(x6)(x7)(x8)(x9)(x10),circle,draw,dashed,inner sep=0pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you do this with an ovaloid shape? Also, are the points you placed points from which arrows can emanate and be directed toward?

Comment: Page 189 of the [TikZ & pgf manual](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) shows you how to do it. It should give the desired result if you just replace `circle` in the last node of Toms example with `ellipse` (this might only work for newer versions of TikZ).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my try at a very basic example in TikZ. My installation of Tikz doesn't know the `ellipse` key for the fitting, but as said above, recent installations should know it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
    \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,0) (a) {o};

\node at (-0.5,-1) (b1) {o};
\node at (0.5,-1) (b2) {o};
\draw [->] (a) -- (b1);
\draw [->] (a) -- (b2);

\node at (-0.75,-2) (c1) {o};
\node at (0,-2) (c2) {o};
\node at (0.75,-2) (c3) {o};
\draw [->] (b1) -- (c1);
\draw [->] (b1) -- (c2);
\draw [->] (b2) -- (c1);
\draw [->] (b2) -- (c3);

\node at (-1,-3) (d1) {o};
\node at (-0.5,-3) (d2) {o};
\node at (0,-3) (d3) {o};
\node at (0.25,-2.75) (d4) {o};
\node at (0.5,-3.25) (d5) {o};
\node at (1,-3) (d6) {o};
\draw [->] (c1) -- (d1);
\draw [->] (b2) to[out=-120,in=60] (d1);
\draw [->] (c2) -- (d2);
\draw [->] (c2) -- (d3);
\draw [->] (c2) -- (d4);
\draw [->] (c3) -- (d5);
\draw [->] (c3) -- (d6);

\node [draw=red,fit=(a),label=0:A] {};
\node [draw=blue,fit=(b1) (b2),label=0:B] {};
\node [draw=green,fit=(c1) (c2) (c3),label=0:C] (C) {};
\node [draw=cyan,fit=(d1) (d2) (d3) (d4) (d5) (d6),label=0:D] (D) {};

\node at (3,0) (e) {o};
\node at (3,-1) (f) {o};
\node at (3,-2) (g) {o};
\node at (3,-3) (h) {o};
\draw [->] (e) -- (f);
\draw [->] (f) -- (g);
\draw [->] (g) -- (h);

\draw [->] (2,-2) -- (2.5,-2) node [midway,above] {\(\theta\)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package, a few adjustment and minor improvements one could do the following.

There are a few comments in the code.

You can use the `backgrounds` library and use

```
insert after arrows={
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
     <everything inside here will be drawn behind everything else>
  \end{scope}
}
```

if you want to have something behind everything else. This is used for the C cloud to show how `crossing over` works.

There are advanced ways around this, of course.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,fit,backgrounds}
\newcommand*{\tikzcdset}{\pgfqkeys{/tikz/commutative diagrams}}
\tikzset{cd/.code={\tikzcdset{#1}}}
\makeatletter
\tikzcdset{% Insert arbitrary code after and before the arrow get drawn
  insert before arrows/.style={/tikz/commutative diagrams/matrix of math nodes maybe/.append code={
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikzcd@savedpaths\expandafter{\tikzcd@savedpaths#1}}},
  insert after arrows/.style={/tikz/execute at end picture={#1}}}
\makeatother
\tikzcdset{
  % What now follows are a few quick fixes to the 'crossing over' style.
  % The actual line is now a decoration that doesn't start right at the border of the nodes as this would over-draw other lines.
  % Of course we could just draw the crossing lines first and then every other line but that means more work.
  % 'coc' stands for 'corssing over clearance'
  %% The following style set only the factor to the 'crossing over clearance' value
  coc </.initial=3,coc >/.initial=3,coc/.style={coc <={#1},coc >={#1}},no coc/.style={coc >=0,coc <=0},
  crossing over/.style={% re-definition, you can add arbitrary styles with 'crossing over=<styles>'
    /tikz/preaction={
      /tikz/draw=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/background color},
      /tikz/arrows=-,
      /tikz/line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/crossing over clearance},
      /tikz/decoration={
        name=curveto,pre=moveto,post=moveto,
        pre length=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/coc <}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/crossing over clearance},
        post length=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/coc >}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/crossing over clearance}},
      /tikz/decorate,#1}},%
  name/.style={% I want to give a name to the inner matrix
    /tikz/every matrix/.append style={name={#1}}}}
\tikzcdset{% the 'dotted diagram' style activates the styles and what not for the diagram that doesn't use any contents in the
  dotted diagram/.style={
    cd={
      diagrams={
        crossing over clearance=+2pt, % the crossing-over area was to big for my taste
        arrows={/tikz/arrows=-},      % I don't want no arrows nowhere
        cells={                       % It's a matrix.
          nodes={
            shape=circle,
            inner sep=+0pt,
            outer sep=+0pt,
            minimum size=+1.5pt,
            fill}}}}}}
\tikzset{% now the dotted line is a node (the shape is not specified here)
  cloud/.style args={#1:#2}{
    draw,
    dashed,
    fit={#1},
    label={north east:{#2}}}}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{/tikz/commutative diagrams/dotted diagram}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  row sep=1cm,
  column sep=.5cm,
  name=m, % for the nodes, is needed in the to fitted nodes
  insert after arrows={% this stuff is drawn after the arrows and thus over-draw/fill these
    \node[circle,cloud=(m-1-4):$A$]{};
    \node[rounded corners,cloud=(m-2-3)(m-2-5):$B$]{};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \node[rounded corners,cloud=(m-3-3)(m-3-5):$C$,fill=red!20]{};
    \end{scope}
  },
  insert before arrows={% this is drawn before all arrows, you can see this very good where the bended line crosses one arrow and the border of the D cloud
    \node[rounded corners,cloud=(m-4-4)(m-5-1)(m-5-6)(m-6-4):$D$]{};}
  ]
 % Let's start.
 % The A cloud
    &    &    & {} \dlar \drar \\
 % The B cloud
    &    & {} \dar \drar 
              &    & {}  \arrow[crossing over]{dll} \dar 
              \\
 % The C cloud
    &    & {} \arrow{ddll}
              & {} \arrow{ddll} \arrow{ddl} \dar
                   & {} \arrow{dddl} \arrow{ddr}
                         \\
 % The D cloud
    &    &    & {} &    &    \\[-.8cm]
 {} \arrow[bend right, crossing over]{uuurrrr} \arrow{uurr}
    & {} & {} &    &    & {} \\[-.8cm]
    &    &    & {}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I might end up using this actually, as I can't get ASYMPTOTE to work.